# How to track what changed between 2 events in a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My `STORE_TOPIC` is a compacted topic that contains the current state of my entities, based on events consumed from `EVENTS_TOPIC` (by a Kafka Streams app). The main purpose of this `STORE_TOPIC` is to be loaded as (global) KTable.

```
EVENTS_TOPIC                    |    STORE_TOPIC
                                |    
VALUE                           |     KEY      VALUE
{"entity":"A", "a":1, "b":2}    |     A        {"a":1, "b":2}
{"entity":"B", "c":3}           |     B        {"c":3}
{"entity":"A", "d":4}           |     A        {"a":1, "b":2, "d":4}
{"entity":"A", "a":0, "e":5}    |     A        {"a":0, "b":2, "d":4, "e":5}
```

A new consumer needs to get notified when changes happen on a defined subset of attributes.

> As an example, if we decided to track the changes on attributes "a", "b" and "c", the expected output would be :

```
A        {"a":1, "b":2}
B        {"c":3}
(Nothing)
A        {"a":0, "b":2}
```

To do this, I wrote a new Kafka Streams App that:

- Handles a "local store" that contains the needed attributes per each key
- Loads `STORE_TOPIC` as a stream
- Compare the incoming message with the content of the "local store" (thanks to a `.transform()`)
- If a change is detected, writes the incoming message (only the attributes we need to track) in a new `OUT_TOPIC` and add/replace the entry in the "local store"

Is there a easier, more elegant way, to achieve this?

**Can you confirm that if I load the `STORE_TOPIC` directly as a KTable : `.table(STORE_TOPIC)` , I can only access the current state of the entity, and there's no way to access a previous version of the entity and operate a comparison on it?**

Comment: You say your app load the `store_topic` as a stream. You should be loading the `events_topic` as a stream. I guess this is a typo.

Comment: My first app (the one that feed the `STORE_TOPIC` with what comes into `EVENTS_TOPIC`) loads the `STORE_TOPIC` as a KTable and streams what arrives in the `EVENTS_TOPIC` and sends a new event in the "store" topic if needed. 

My **second app** needs to detect the changes in what lays in the `STORE_TOPIC`. And to detect changes in this `STORE_TOPIC`, I stream it and rebuild a local store, only with the subset of attributes.

Comment: Ok. Understood. Not sure why you need two apps for this though. I am quite sure this can be done within a single topology with not too much code.

Comment: Yes. Agreed, this can easily be done in the same app. (Or my second app could stream from `EVENTS_TOPIC` with a topology very similar to the 1st app.) But the `STORE_TOPIC` is massively used by other apps/consumers, whereas the new so-called `OUT_TOPIC` is very specific to one consumer and it will probably disappear in a near future. So from a design perspective, I'd prefer not to merge the 2 features in the same topology.(Keep it stupid, simple!) What I had in mind was something like "When the state changes (`STORE_TOPIC`) then trigger something to `OUT_TOPIC` if needed".